# java.lang.NullPointerException at android.app.Activity.setRequestedOrientation(Activity.java:4453)

Tags: java, android

I have this error **on some devices** caused by this code:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

How i can resolve it? thank you!

Error is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at android.app.Activity.setRequestedOrientation(Activity.java:4453)
```

Comment: `this` is apparently null. Why don't you look at the source code of the method `setRequestedOrientation` to check it out?

Comment: @mikeyaworski `this` can *never* be null. The only way for that line to throw an NPE is if `ActivityInfo` is a *variable* (is it?) which evaluates to null - or that's not the real line.

Comment: thank you for your reply sir..  when i pass the mouse over this, it's appears that eclipse has found the activity, how i can make it work on other android devices? is there an alternative

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on?

Comment: @user3219446 Make sure to post the *full* stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are trying to lock the activity into a specific orientation, then you can always handle it from the AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activityName"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

Adding the `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` is the attribute that does this for you.